# `runGet` exits prematurely

Tags: haskell

I am using Data.Binary to decode binary files and found that the `runGet` function would throw an exception “not enough bytes” even though it has not consumed all the input.

Specifically, in the loop I am repeatedly trying to parse the binary file until it has consumed all the input

```
parsePCAP = do 
    gHeader <- parseGHeader 
    packets <- parsePPackets [] 
    let packets' = catMaybes packets 
    return (Pcap gHeader packets')
  where 
    parsePPackets xs = do 
    empty <- isEmpty 
    if empty 
        then return xs 
        else do p <- parseB6034 
                parsePPackets (p:xs)
```

When I try to run this function with `runGet`, the exception “Data.Binary.Get.runGet at position 3293603: not enough bytes” would be thrown, while the total length of input is 5864230, a number significantly larger. The function `parseB6034` consumes no more than 250 bytes in each round. In addition, the `parsePPackets` works well when fed with a small amount of data.

Is it the problem of my code or an error with the package binary? The ByteString fed into `runGet` is lazy ByteString, as required by `runGet` function.

Below is the complete code

```
module Header (
  PGlobalHeader(..)
, Transaction(..)
, MarketData(..)
, Pcap(..)

, parsePCAP 
) where 

import Data.Int 
import Data.Word 
import Control.Monad
import Data.Maybe 
import Control.Monad.IO.Class

import qualified Data.ByteString as BS 
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as Char8
import Data.Binary.Get 
import Data.Text (Text)
import Data.Text.Encoding 

import Lib (source)

data PGlobalHeader = PGHeader { 
  magic_number  :: Word32 
, version_major :: Word16 
, version_minor :: Word16 
, timezone      :: Int32  -- GMT to local correction 
, sigfigs       :: Word32 -- accuracy of timestamps 
, snaplen       :: Word32 -- max length of captured packets 
, network       :: Word32 -- data link type 
} deriving (Show, Eq)

data Transaction = Trans { 
  qty   :: Text
, price :: Text
} deriving (Show, Eq)

data MarketData = B6034 {
  issCode :: Text -- issue code (ISIN code) 
, accTime :: Text -- accepted time 
, bids    :: [Transaction] -- from 1st to 5th
, asks    :: [Transaction]
} deriving (Show, Eq)

data Pcap = Pcap PGlobalHeader [MarketData] 
deriving Show

parseGHeader :: Get PGlobalHeader 
parseGHeader = PGHeader <$> 
           getWord32le <*> 
           getWord16le <*> 
           getWord16le <*>
           getInt32le <*>
           getWord32le <*> 
           getWord32le <*> 
           getWord32le 

parsePPacket :: (BS.ByteString -> Bool) -> -- discard the packet?
            Get a -> -- packet parser 
            Get (Maybe a) 
parsePPacket f p = do 
    skip 12
    plen <- getWord32le -- length of pcap packet 
    skip 42 -- skip the IP/UDP header 
    code <- getByteString 5 
    if f code 
        then do r <- p 
                return (Just r)
        else do skip' (plen - 47)
                return Nothing 
  where 
    skip' = skip . fromIntegral 
    getByteString' = getByteString . fromIntegral

parseB6034 :: Get (Maybe MarketData)
parseB6034 = parsePPacket (BS.isPrefixOf quote) parseB6034' 
 where 
  quote :: BS.ByteString
  quote = Char8.pack "B6034"

  parseB6034' :: Get MarketData 
  parseB6034' = do
      issCode <- mkText 12 
      skip 12 
      bids <- go 5  
      skip 7
      asks <- go 5  
      skip 50 
      accTime <- mkText 8
      skip 1 
      return (B6034 issCode accTime bids asks)
    where 
      go 0 = return [] 
      go n = do price <- mkText 5  
                qty <- mkText 7
                remains <- go (n-1)  
                return $ (Trans qty price) : remains 

mkText :: Int -> Get Text 
mkText = fmap decodeLatin1 . getByteString 

parsePCAP = do 
    gHeader <- parseGHeader 
    packets <- parsePPackets [] 
    let packets' = catMaybes packets 
    return (Pcap gHeader packets')
  where 
    parsePPackets xs = do 
    empty <- isEmpty 
    if empty 
        then return xs 
        else do p <- parseB6034 
                parsePPackets (p:xs)
```

Comment: Try using Debug.Trace to find out what your code is doing in practice. One possibility is that you are getting out of synch with your binary format at some point, and hence maybe "plen" winds up being a very big number which your "skip' (plen - 47)" then tries to obey. But without more clues its very difficult to tell.

Comment: @PaulJohnson thank you for the suggestion! The error occurred because one of the package lengths is 46, which is smaller than 47 and would cause arithmetic overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the correct way to close the problem. If not please point out the right way to do it.

The basic problem is that I am using `Word32` to represent the package length and one of the pcap packets is shorter than 47. A shorter number subtracted from 47 would result in arithmetic overflow and cause the `Get` monad to skip the biggest number of bytes that `Word32` can represent.